# Replacing a .NET type at runtime

Tags: .net

I have a .NET assembly which has defined a type `T` at compile time, and I have instantiated an object `my_t` as an instance of this type.

I am wondering if it is possible in .NET to use the runtime compiler services to re-compile this class, then load the new class definition into the currently executing assembly, so when I call methods off of `my_t`, they will use the new code.

I am not changing the signatures of any of the methods, just the method bodies.

Any .NET gurus out there know if this is possible? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I would never do something like this. Why not use inheritance?

Comment: Yeah - what's the use case? Why not use plugin architecture? Compile your dynamic plugin and load it, obviously passing your plugin interface around.

Comment: i agree with the previous speaker. this way, when i invoke a method in a class, i cannot know for sure what it'll do *even if i have access to the code* . sounds chaotic, and that's what OO is all about preventing. what you want can probably be achieved by a dependency injection pattern

Comment: While the above comments do focus on best practices (and I have to concur), you should note that best practices aren't always an option, and weird screw-ball hacks are the only way to make something work (i.e. maybe he doesn't control the assembly, or the classes calling the method he wants to replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .NET object can't change type at runtime; it's a fundamental assumption in the CLR.

A few suggestions:

1. Write the code for `T` to forward calls to the right type as appropriate. It can forward to a type that gets compiled at runtime if you want to.
2. Use some kind of aspect-orientated or dynamic proxy framework to automate (1) for you
3. If this kind of forwarding isn't suitable, I believe there is a .NET profiling API available to native that lets you intercept the JIT process. All I know of this is that tools like NCover are able to inject their own machine code this way.

Comment: I think your suggest #1 is very promising - I have a prototype working now. One question is whether calling my_t.GetType().GetMethod("my_method_name") is a major performance hit versus calling, say, my_t.my_method_name directly. Any idea?

Comment: It's a dreadful performance hit. Take a look at ashish.s's Castle Dynamic Proxy suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

You **can** swap method implementations, but **ONLY** if running unsafe code is an option, and the methods you want to swap have not been NGen'd or "Zapped".

The basic procedure is pretty simple in concept: you swap the memory address of where the method's JIT'd code resides with the memory address of another method's JIT'd code (you can also force the CLR to JIT your methods in the first place, to avoid a weird prerequisite issue).

There is a great proof-of-concept project up on CodeProject.com: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer

Go check it out!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that is possible, but if it is, it sounds like an awfully messy solution.

Use a plugin architecture, so you can dynamically compile your generated plugin, inheriting from your plugin interface and simply load that type from your newly created assembly and inject it into your plugin container.

Answer (score 2):

you can use castle dynamic proxy to create a proxy of your class. The proxy is a new type that would let you inject new implementation, but anything that you want to inject would have to declared as virtual.

Comment: Interesting - I assume you're talking about http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html - have you used this? How is performance impacted, if you happen to know? Thx!

Comment: I have used it in one my projects, the performance impact should stabilize, since its actually generating code and compiling it into an assembly for your types.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my comment:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {

    }
}

public class Sub : Base
{
    public override void Method()
    {

    }
}

public void DoStuff<T>() where T : Base, new()
{
    var instance = new T();
    instance.Method();
}
```