# Hide or remove class inside DLL and replace with another class (same name) outside the DLL

Tags: .net, dll

I have a DLL that has a class that throws some errors (that makes the whole DLL useless). I don't have access to the source code (lost it) and like to just ignore the class and replace it with the same class outside the DLL (but without the errors of course).

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your dll internally use that class or just export it?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1862561/395718

Comment: It uses it internally

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, right here:

> I don't have access to the source code (lost it)

Best solution: ***Find It***

Otherwise you are using code you don't control, don't understand, and where don't know what it does.

You might consider asking a question here along the lines of "Where can I find source code for this product" or "Where can I find a replacement library".