# CSharpCodeProvider override, recompile or replace an existing function by dynamic compilation

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider, dynamic-compilation

I have looked every resources in the net and I could not find any answer!

I want to know if its possible to override or recompile a function in the parent application by Dynamic Compilation, by using C# CSharpCodeProvider.

I have provide a simple pseudocode as shown below.

the Test class is what I want to override or recompile.

```
class Test 
{
    public virtual void Testing1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method1");
    }
}
```

What actually I want to do is to dynamically compile the 'source' and override the Test.Testing1. I think my idea has many problems, please guide me.

```
source= @"
    class Test
{
    public override void Testing1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(""Method2"");
    }
}
"

     Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"CompilerVersion", "v4.0"}
            };
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateInMemory = true,
            GenerateExecutable = false,
        };
        var assemblies = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
        var assemblyLocations = assemblies.Select(a => Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(a.FullName).Location).ToList();
        assemblyLocations.Add(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblyLocations.ToArray());
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);
```

As conclusion, Lets say if I execute the below code before dynamic compilation, the output would be "Method 1".

```
Test test = new Test();
test.Testing1();
```

and if I execute the same code after compilation, I want to get "Method 2" as output.

Comment: Isn't your problem that the `Test` method you're compiling doesn't inherit from the original `Test` class?

Comment: let me edit my question with more details

Comment: I mean, you can't override a base class method if the "derived" class isn't actually derived from that base class.

Comment: updated the question, hope its clear now.

Comment: I think the closest you'll get is what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10547567/3181933), but I think that's only after the type is instantiated. If you don't have access to the code creating instances of this type, then I don't think you can even substitute a proxy type.

Comment: Perhaps it could help
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93322/generating-a-class-dynamically-from-types-that-are-fetched-at-runtime